# Difference between ArticleStartDate and Publish startdate columns

Tags: column

What is the difference between these columns:

ArticleStartDate:

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField id="ArticleStartDate" FieldName="ArticleStartDate" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField>
```

Publish startdate:

```
<PublishingWebControls:PublishingScheduleFieldControl FieldName="51d39414-03dc-4bd0-b777-d3e20cb350f7" runat="server"/>
```